# pandas drop duplicates doesn't return dataframe with duplicates removed

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.Dataframe({'src':['A','B','C'],'trg':['A','C','B'],'wgt':[1,3,7]})
```

I want to drop the duplicates from this dataframe for columns `src` and `trg`

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['src','trg'],keep='first',inplace=False)
```

This should drop the first row where `src=A` and `trg='A'`

But this is not happening. There is no change in the dataframe.  What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `df[df['src'] != df['trg']]`?

Comment: That worked and removed all the duplicates without keeping at least one pair. But can you suggest why drop_duplicates is not working?

Comment: That's because, in both rows, the values of src and trg are not the same. When you use the subset, it looks for duplicates in the entire subset.

Comment: Drop_duplicates works for columns. That is if you have another row with `B C` as source and target, that row will be dropped.

Comment: OK. That was a very subtle point I missed. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

TO remove the duplicate, you can refer to the following example which I have solved on pyNb  [image]

Or use df = df[df['src'] != df['trg']]